# Unix script using awk

Tags: unix, awk

I  have a problem and I dont know why my code doesn't work

the code:

```
prot="abc"
awk '{
if ( $1 == $prot )
     print $2
}' file.txt
```

but when I change my code to this it works as it was intented to work

```
awk '{
if ( $1 == "abc" )
     print $2
}' file.txt
```

Why is that happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use a bash variable directly into your script.

Instead, give it with the `-v` option:

```
-v prot="$prot"
```

All together:

```
prot="abc"
awk -v prot="$prot" '{
if ( $1 == prot )
     print $2
}' file.txt
```

Comment: +1.. but please fix the all together code block.. :-)

Comment: I get `improper assignment -v prot="$prot"{..`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an other variation:

```
prot="abc"
awk '{
if ( $1 == prot )
     print $2
}' prot="$prot" file.txt
```